# Why $\mu>1$ distinguishes 2 cases?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, convex-analysis

Let $f(\theta)=\sum_i\theta^i P(i)$ where $P(i)$ is a probability distribution of $i=1,\dots, n,\dots$ with $i\in Z$ and $0\leq \theta\leq 1$. Denote $G$ the graph of $f(\theta)$ where $\theta$ ranges in $(0,1)$.

Then $f(0)=P(0)$ and $f(1)=1$. Let $\mu=\sum_i iP(i)$ be the expectation value of $i$.

$\textbf{Q:}$ The book draws two graphs which distinguishes 2 cases. If $\mu\geq 1$. Then $G$ intersects $h(\theta)=\theta$'s graph in $(0,1)$ part at only 1 point $0<\theta'<1$ If $\mu<1$, then $G$ does not intersect $h(\theta)=\theta$'s graph in $(0,1)$. In other words, how do I show that $f(\theta)\geq\theta$ for $\mu<1$ case in $\theta\in (0,1)$ and the other case for only 1 intersection?

Comment: The graphs _always_ intersect at $(1,1)$, so your $\mu<1$ statement is slightly wrong.

Comment: @kimchilover Sorry for confusion. I should have used $(0,1)$ interval instead of $[0,1]$. They always intersect at least 1 point $(1,1)$. The difference is whether there is a root between $(0,1)$ or not.

Comment: OK. The secret hint is that the function $f$ is convex on $[0,\infty)$, and unless $\mu=0$, is strictly convex.